# Improving a query to find out-of-sync values between two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  tableOneId
  SUM(a+b+c) AS tableOneData,
  MIN(d) AS tableTwoData,
FROM
  tableTwo JOIN tableOne ON tableOneId = tableTwoId
GROUP BY
  tableOneId
```

All of the mentioned columns are declared as `numeric(30,6) NOT NULL`.

In `tableOne`, I have entries whose sum (columns `a, b, c`) should be equivalent to column `d` in `Table Two`.

A simple example of this:

```
Table One (id here should read tableOneId to match above query)
  id=1, a=1, b=0, c=0
  id=1, a=0, b=2, c=0
  id=2, a=1, b=0, c=0

Table Two (id here should read tableTwoId to match above query)
  id=1, d=3
  id=2, d=1
```

My first iteration used `SUM(d)/COUNT(*)` but division is messy so I'm currently using `MIN(d)`. What would be a better way to write this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  tableOneId,
  tableOneData,
  d AS tableTwoData
FROM tableTwo
JOIN (select tableOneId, sum(a + b + c) AS tableOneData
      from tableone
      group by 1) x ON tableOneId = tableTwoId
where tableOneData <> d;
```

This will return all rows that have incorrect data in table 2.

Comment: Nope, you've missed the point. Look at the first example, where the sum of a, b and c from two different rows produced a single d. So the op is right when he/she is thinking in aggregates. Your solution would be correct if the first example from the description of the issue would be impossible.

Comment: I think the inner select needs a `GROUP BY tableOneId`? Otherwise this seems to do the job.

Comment: @nevets1219 Ah yes... I've added in the group by. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select tableOneId, SUM(a) + SUM(b) + SUM(c) as tableOneData, d as tableTwoData
from  tableTwo JOIN tableOne ON tableOneId = tableTwoId
GROUP BY tableOneId, d
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is incorrect because of `d as tableTwoData` (not in aggregate)